# Bootstrap: Creating Multiple Popovers with Button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way I can create multiple popovers with one button click?  Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is create popup tips in different sections when "Show Tips" is pressed.  (i.e. on pressing "show tips", a popover window appears  for the input box and another popover appears on the picture) This is what I have so far, but I haven't been able to figure out how to create multiple popovers.

Bonus points for creating focus elements (i.e. tip popover and element are highlighted and background becomes darker)

http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/dzbuvdku/

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})

$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
 height:1000px;
 width:700px;

background:#E9EAED;
float:left;
padding:10px 10px 0px 10px;

}

.top-container{
padding-top:10px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-left:10px;
height:170px;
width:100%;
background:white;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #B3B6B5;
position:relative;

}

.input-lg{
height:60px;
border-radius:3px;
border:gray 1px solid;
}

/* --------------------------------------------Features */
.features{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
}
.features > button{
 text-align:center;
 background:white;
 border:none;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.features >button>img{
 
}
.features> button.closer{

}
img:hover{
background:#EAE6E6;
transition: 0.3s ease;
}

/* --------------------------------------------Second Container */
.second-container{
 width:100%;
 background:white;

 margin-top:20px;
 border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #B3B6B5;

}

.postinfo{
 display:inline;
}
img.person{
 float:left;
 margin:10px;
}
.postinfo >h4{
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
.postinfo>h6{
 margin-top:0px;
}

img.ramen{
 width:100%;
}

/* --------------------------------------------New User */
.newuser{
 height:30px;
}

/* --------------------------------------------Show Tips */
.newuser{
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container wrapper">
  <!-- =========Section: Show Tips?=========== -->
  <div class="newuser">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
Show Tips
</button>

  </div>
  <!-- =========Section: Top Container=========== -->
  <div class="top-container">
   <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Say something...To tag people to this post, just type their @username">
   <div class="features">
    <button><img src="img/photo.gif" alt="Photo" class="img-rounded"></button>
    <button class="closer"><img src="img/video.gif" alt="Video" class="img-rounded"></button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- =========Section: Second Container=========== -->
  <div class="second-container">
   <img src="img/person.png" alt="" class="person">
   <div class="postinfo">
    <h4><b>Name Surname</b></h4>
    <h6>Today at 11:56</h6>
    <span>This is a description.  This is a description.  This !s a description.</span>
    <img src="img/ramen.jpg" alt="" class="ramen">
   </div>


  </div>


 </div><!-- =========End: Containing Wrapper=========== -->
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers
This is a popover

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/dzbuvdku/1/ I will explain the changes in detail once you confirm your expectation.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, I actually figured it out but what I'm trying to work out right now is how to toggle it, so when I press the button again, the popovers dissappear and if I press again, they come back.

Comment: Looks like it's as simple as replacing "show" with "toggle" :)

Comment: Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/dzbuvdku/3/

Comment: Perfect, better than my solution!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

- Add data-toggle, data-trigger and other necessary attributes as mentioned in bootstrap for all the controls where you want to show popover
- Add a class, let's say 'tip-container' for all the controls where you want to show popover
- Finally, toggle the popover on the 'tip-container' object during click event of the button

http://jsfiddle.net/dzbuvdku/3/

```
<input type="email" class="form-control input-lg tip-container" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Say something...To tag people to this post, just type their @username" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="Some tip 1" data-placement="bottom">
            <div class="features">
                <button><img src="img/photo.gif" alt="Photo" class="img-rounded tip-container" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="Some tip 2" data-placement="bottom"></button>
                <button class="closer"><img src="img/video.gif" alt="Video" class="img-rounded"></button>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#ShowTipsBtn').on('click', function()
{    
    $('.tip-container').popover('toggle');    
});
```

if you want to change the button text during toggle, here is an option:

```
$('#ShowTipsBtn').on('click', function()
{    
    if ($(this).text() == "Show Tips")
    {
        $('.tip-container').popover('show');
        $(this).text('Hide Tips');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.tip-container').popover('destroy');
        $(this).text('Show Tips');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help and solution!  Works perfectly